# issue with device.send_command method from netmiko connecthandler

Tags: python, networking, cisco

language : python 2.7

module : netmiko

method: send_command

device: IOS cisco_3750

protocol : telnet

problem description : while sending any command with more then four strings there is an I/O error

```
error:
 example device.send_command(show aaa user all)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo-L460\Desktop\yo.py", line 11, in <module>
    output=lala.send_command("show aaa user all")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1051, in send_command
    search_pattern))
IOError: Search pattern never detected in send_command_expect: testingnew\#
```

---

Kindly notice **testingnew** is the host name for the device in enable mode
script is working fine with sending two strings example device.send_command(show ?) is working fine

Comment: It is complaining that it never saw the router prompt after you sent the command.

I would turn on debugging and see if it gave you more clues. You might need to update your question with some of that information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kirk Byers, i collected the trace of the and saw issue was happening because of terminal length, first page data was there there in the trace terminal was expecting an input to view next page, i fixed the terminal length and issue was sorted.

Comment: What is your solution exactly? Can you explain step by step?